# Create a Method to add components in Selected JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, methods, awt, jtabbedpane

I am a newbie, and I have already passed some days to get the idea, but could not solve it, if anyone can help me.

I have main two `JPanel` in one `JFrame`. I have some buttons in the first panel. I have One method to add a panel to the`JTabbedPane` by calling another method to create that `JPanels` then add it to the Tab.

I want a method which will add any buttons/components to the Selected tab which I want whenever I click the button from the first panel.
How can I do this. I can post those three method's code here if anyone wish to help me. Thanks in advance.

The first code add new tabs to the `JTabbedPane`,

```
private class TabPlus implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel panel = CreateSlice();
            String title = "Slice " + String.valueOf(pane.getTabCount());
            pane.insertTab(title, null, panel, null, pane.getTabCount() - 1);
        }
    }
```

The second code is for selecting the tabs,

```
private class TabSelect implements ChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JTabbedPane source = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
            if (source.getSelectedComponent() != null) {
                int index = source.getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.print(index);
            }

        }
    }
```

This creates the `JPanel` to be added to the `JTabbedPane`,

```
public JPanel CreateSlice() {

    JPanel Slice = new JPanel();
    Slice.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 600));
    return Slice;

}
```

The buttons are in another Panel with their own action.

[GUI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFYfk.png)

Comment: Share your code so we can take a look at it.

Comment: yes, exactly, but these buttons are in another panel, so whenever it will be selected, the action with this button will create those buttons or any other component (e.g. textbox, lists.) on that selected tab.

Comment: Why don't you the buttons, to all your JTabbedPane and set their vibility to false and whenever a JTabbedPane gets selected you set the visibility to true.

Comment: That's an good idea, but I have a method which adds tabs to the `JTabbedPane` by calling a public method for creating the panels. Now it seems complicated to me, how can I do this?

Comment: Hi @NAIT, did I explain clearly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I found one way to do this, My index variable   `int index = source.getSelectedIndex();` must be public variable, then in Action event of the buttons from another tab will add component to this selected `JTabbedPane`.

In my case I introduced and `ArrayList` of panel (network_slices), and every time I am adding a panel to the `JTabbedPane`, it is also adding to the `ArrayList`. then I called the panel from the ArrayList by using the index of selected JTabbedPane. Here is the part of the code.

```
private class TabSelect implements ChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        JTabbedPane source = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
        if (source.getSelectedComponent() != null) {
            index = source.getSelectedIndex();
            System.out.print(index);
        }
    }
}

private class AddTab implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Slice panel = new Slice();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 600));
            String title = "Slice " + String.valueOf(pane.getTabCount());
            pane.insertTab(title, null, panel, null, pane.getTabCount() - 1);
            network_slices.add(panel);
        }
    }

private class AddNetworkFuncitons implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String buttonselected = (String) e.getActionCommand();
            JButton button = new JButton(buttonselected);
            network_slices.get(index).add(button).setVisible(true);
            System.out.print(buttonselected);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a panel with butttons this way:

```
public JPanel CreateSlice() {

    JPanel Slice = new JPanel();
    Slice.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 600));

    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel.add(new JButton("dumpButton"));
    buttonsPanel.setVisible(false);
    Slice.add(buttonsPanel);

    return Slice;

}
```

And whenever a selection occurs set the visibility of buttonsPanel to true.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try this, but I don't want tab-selection will make this button visible, I want the buttons from the other panel will make this button visible, but in a selected tab-panel.

Comment: Yes, I also can do this by `ActionListener` , but how to do this in a selected tab panel ?

Comment: I have buttons (B1,B2,B3) in left panel (in a class) of the frame. I am adding the tabs in the `JTabbedPane` in right `JPanel` of the frame, lets say Tab1, Tab2, Tab3,... (in another class). Now I want like this, I will first select the tab (Tab1/2/3), in any one of the Tab, I will create a button B11 by clicking B1, and/or B22 by clicking B2.

Comment: I have added the image